# Read and play Wav file in delphi

Tags: delphi, audio

How can I play uncompressed wav files in delphi?
I mean reading the wav file byte by byte and sending the data directly to the speaker.
I have searched the internet and found some functions for playing sound for a specified period of time. for example: `myplaysoundfunc(1200, 100)`. this will play a sound of 1200Hz for 100 milliseconds.
But playing a wav file is more complicated. I have problem with `Samples per second` and `bits per samples`.

Comment: TMediaPlayer handles everything itself. you just tell it to open a file and play it. But what I want is to open a wav file and read it byte by byte and put the data in an array of samples, then play it through the sound card. But I have problem with the amount of data I have to read according to the SampleRate and BitRate.

Comment: Do you know the format of the file?

Comment: Yes. it's uncompressed Wav file. which has a small header. then all the remaining bytes of the file are sound frequencies which can be played directly through the speaker. it could be `11,025 Hz 16 bit PCM` or `11,025 Hz 8 bit PCM` or some other formats.

Comment: So what's the problem? You understand the format. What are you asking from us?

Comment: There are two parts of this task and it is not clear which one you have problems with: 1) reading the file correctly so you get the information you need from the headers and read the data correctly according to this, and 2) open an output device with the correct parameters that matches your input data and streaming the data to it. Please be more specific.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. I know how a wav file is processed and outputted to the speaker. but I don't know how to implement the system. I don't know how to set the timings. I mean how many bits I have to read in a Second for example. What I need right now is a sample code. I could not find anything useful in the Internet.

Comment: It sounds like you think it is just a few easy lines of code, but it is not. There is a lot of things to understand, so even if the code (300+ lines) was posted here, it would be a lot of work explaining it.

Comment: I'm sure there are plenty of example codes on the web for decoding wav files

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any components or external libraries for this.

Full application sourcecode, taken from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Play_recorded_sounds#Delphi :

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
program PlayRecordedSounds;
uses MMSystem;
begin
  sndPlaySound('SoundFile.wav', SND_NODEFAULT OR SND_ASYNC);
end.
```

With these parameters the sound plays on the background while your app keeps running.
If you use `SND_SYNC` instead of `SND_ASYNC`, your application waits for the sound to finish before continuing.

You can also let the sound loop if you add `SND_LOOP`. 
This procedure stops sounds that you've previously played, unless you add `SND_NOSTOP`. That way, the old sound keeps playing.

Notes:

- This will only work on Windows. For FireMonkey there are other options.
- If you really want to play sample-by-sample, things get more complicated. In that case I advise to use a library to help you out with that, like the [Delphi ASIO/VST library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/delphiasiovst/).

Comment: I've seen ASIO/VST and some other libraries like BASS. but these libraries do all the things themselves. I want to be able to read data from a wav file and send it to the Speaker directly without any third-party libraries. I know how to output a specific frequency through the speaker. I need to know how much data should I read from the WAV file and send it to the speaker in a Second.